# connect disscussion board to outlook

Tags: list, permissions, outlook

I created a share point discussion board list. Later I attached the list for outlook.

I gave some user authorization of contribute.
And at this time the user can advertise his announcements in the discussion board list,
but he can not create the connection between his item and the outlook.

Is it because of the  user authorizations?
If not why this happens?
If yes how it's possible to rise on the problem?

thanks
liron :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create per item connections to Outlook, you make the connection at the list level.  When the user navigates to the discussion board, do they have the Actions, Connect To Outlook option?

Comment: I thing the main problem was when I used the chrom and no the explorer